# How to get and use camera calibration file?

Tags: ros, calibration, camera1394, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running on Lucid 32-bit from Electric debs. I have been able to run the mono calibration utility with a 1394 camera and get a successful calibration. How do I then get the actual camera calibration file that was saved to disk and use it in a launch file to get rectified images?

**Steps To Reproduce:**

Start [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) and [cameracalibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration) with the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="stereo">
    <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="camera_left">
      <rosparam file="$(find stereo_calibration)/cameras/left_flea2.yaml"/>
      <remap from="camera" to="left"/>
    </node>
  </group>

  <node pkg="camera_calibration" type="cameracalibrator.py" name="mono_calibration"
    args="-size 9x6 -square 0.054 image:=/stereo/left/image_raw camera:=/stereo/left">
  </node>
</launch>
```

and the following yaml file:

```
# ID number of camera. Use Coriander to find it.
guid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# Mode describes the size and number of channels for the images.
video_mode: 1600x1200_mono8
# The frame_id MUST be part of your URDF to display stereo data correctly in Rviz.
frame_id: left_camera
# The location of the ROS calibration file.
camera_info_url: package://stereo_calibration/cameras/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_mono.yaml
# Frames per second.
frame_rate: 30
# Try to reset the camera when opening.
reset_on_open: true
# Change from default 400Mbps Firewire.
iso_speed: 800
```

So far so good, as I get the utility to show up, all the bars go green, I can click 'Save' and 'Commit', and then exit out of the launch file.

There is a file created at */tmp/calibrationdata.tar.gz* that I am able to open and see 74 images plus a file named *ost.txt*. Using the [converter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration_parsers) utility I am able to get a yaml file with the following contents:

```
image_width: 1600
image_height: 1200
camera_name: narrow_stereo/left
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [2379.692159, 0, 810.664016, 0, 2364.724193, 565.047935, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [-0.125793, 0.149249, -0.000565, -0.000972, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [2348.257291, 0, 809.568039, 0, 0, 2344.569053, 563.818346, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I modified the `camera_name` field to be `stereo/left` but it made no difference in the errors described below.

**Errors:**
The output of running a launch file similar to above but with [image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc) and two image viewers is:

```
[ERROR] [1323196102.210752328]: Unable to open camera calibration file [~/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ERROR] [1323196102.427796451]: Unable to open camera calibration file [~/.ros/camera_info/00b09d0100a8f71b.yaml]
... logging to x.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
started roslaunch server http://localhost:58044/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /stereo/camera_left/frame_id
 * /rosdistro
 * /stereo/camera_left/frame_rate
 * /stereo/camera_left/camera_info_url
 * /stereo/camera_left/iso_speed
 * /stereo/camera_left/guid
 * /rosversion
 * /stereo/camera_left/reset_on_open
 * /stereo/camera_left/video_mode

NODES
  /stereo/left/
    left_image_proc (image_proc/image_proc)
  /stereo/
    camera_left (camera1394/camera1394_node)
    left_raw (image_view/image_view)
    left_rect (image_view/image_view)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [30321]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
~/stereo_calibration/stereo_calibration.launch http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to 13b5dbac-2038-11e1-a2b9-5c260a53cca4
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [30334]
started core service [/rosout]
process[stereo/camera_left-2]: started with pid [30341]
process[stereo/left_raw-3]: started with pid [30347]
process[stereo/left_rect-4]: started with pid [30348]
process[stereo/left/left_image_proc-5]: started with pid [30349]
[stereo/left/left_image_proc-5] killing on exit
[stereo/left_rect-4] killing on exit
[stereo/left_raw-3] killing on exit
[stereo/camera_left-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

The two image viewers are used to view `/stereo/left/image_raw` and `/stereo/left/image_rect`. Both of the images look identical, where I would expect the rectification to crop parts of the rectified image. Running [rxgraph](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxgraph) shows the nodes connected as I would expect them to be connected.

**More Specific Questions**

1. Am I saving the calibration files correctly?
2. Do I have to use the conversion tool to get the calibration files into the correct format?
3. Is using the `package://` or `file://` tag the correct way to load the calibration file from the yaml file?
4. Should I see a noticeable difference when viewing the raw and rectified images?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12193/how-to-get-and-use-camera-calibration-file?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are doing looks mostly OK. The error messages you got are misleading and irrelevant. There is an [enhancement ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5273) to fix them in Fuerte.

To answer your specific questions:

1. I think so. Clicking the "COMMIT" button on the calibration menu should store the new calibration data at the specified URL, which need not have existed before then, although the package directory should already exist.
2. No.
3. Yes. Electric has a new feature, allowing you to substitute the camera name (GUID) as part of the URL, like `package://stereo_calibration/cameras/${NAME}.yaml`. For your device, that would resolve to `package://stereo_calibration/cameras/00b09d0100a8f71b.yaml` (reference to [api doc](http://docs.ros.org/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#details))
4. Maybe not, depending on how good your lenses are.

The `camera_name` in the saved calibration file should be `00b09d0100a8f71b` for your device. It should get set automatically. If the calibrated name does not agree with the actual device GUID, a warning will be logged.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-12-06**:
I like it better. I tried to do it originally, but the formatting wouldn't work out as it always wanted to indent the numbers by ~2 spaces, i.e., 1 looked correct, 2 was 2 spaces to the right of 1, 3 was 2 spaces to the right of 2... Thanks.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-06**:
Good idea. Thanks.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-06**:
I hope you don't mind my edit. I adjusted the original question with numbers; did the same here to match.

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-15**:
In case of other camera drivers like the usb_cam is it the same? How can I find out the camera_name?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
Many camera drivers use camera_info_manager and therefore behave similarly. The usb_cam driver apparently does not, so I don't know how it handles calibration and camera naming.